# Docker still can see open ports with and without --link flag set

Tags: docker

I've been following these two tutorials to understand a bit about Docker networking:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_redis_service/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks

The first tutorial says that the container is not exposing ports by not using -p or -P flags.

```
$ docker run --name redis-server -d <your username>/redis
```

And when running another container it uses the --link flag to "redis" container:

```
$ docker run --name redis-client --link redis:db -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

And that way I can connect from *redis-client* container to *redis-server* container because they are linked. But while experimenting with other configurations, I run another container, let's call it *redis-client-2* -- just after I stoped and removed *redis-client* container -- that doesn't use the --link flag:

```
$ docker run --name redis-client-2 -i -t ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

And I noticed that even without the --link flag set I can connect to *redis-server* container's redis server from *redis-client-2*

My question is, am I misunderstanding the concept of --link and exposed ports on Docker? Why can I still connect to *redis-server* container with or without the --link flag?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers on the same Docker network (if none is setup, `default`) as each other can communicate with each other freely. `--link` is a vestigial feature from before the days of first-class Docker networking.

The `-p` & `-P` options only relate to exposing ports *outside* of the Docker network (i.e. to the host) and has no bearing on container-to-container communication.